# Adding weeks with 0 value to a pandas dataframe with time series data for weeks when data wasn't captured

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have transactional data that I've grouped into weeks. However, I'm not guaranteed to have data every week. Group by has done a great job of filling in missing weeks between the first and last week with 0 quantity. However, I need to fill my dataframe with values up to the present week.

My data is stored in the dateframe dfShipsInScope, and I've transformed my data to be weekly with the code below:

```
dfShipsInScope['START_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(dfShipsInScope['START_TIME'])
dfShipsInScope=dfShipsInScope[['START_TIME','X']].groupby('START_TIME').sum()
dfShipsInScope=dfShipsInScope.resample(rule = 'W-SAT').sum()
dfShipsInScope.index.freq='W-SAT'
```

This outputs something like this:

```
            X
START_TIME  
2019-09-14  3.000
2019-09-21  0.000
2019-09-28  1.500
```

I need to add weeks 2019-10-05 and 2019-10-12 with X=0 in order for the dataframe to reflect weeks up until today. In some instances, I need to add several weeks worth of zeros, so I'm looking for an efficient solution. Does anybody know of a good way to do this?

Comment: Any rhyme or reason just two weeks?

Comment: I'm running this on a lot of different data sets. In this particular example, the last date point was two weeks ago. In other situations, it could certainly be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can reindex your output with `pd.date_range`

In:

```
df.reindex(
    pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(),
                  end=pd.to_datetime('today') + pd.offsets.Week(),
                  freq='W-SAT')).fillna(0)
```

Out:

```
|            | X   |
|------------|-----|
| 2019-09-14 | 3.0 |
| 2019-09-21 | 0.0 |
| 2019-09-28 | 1.5 |
| 2019-10-05 | 0.0 |
| 2019-10-12 | 0.0 |
```